# Segmentation fault calling setvbuf

Tags: c, cygwin, stdio

I'm trying a basic program with `setvbuf`:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE * fp;
    char buffer[1024];

    fp = fopen("~/my.txt", "w");

    setvbuf(fp, buffer, _IOFBF, sizeof(buffer));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I run the program, I hit a segmentation fault on `setvbuf`:

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=0, argv=0x20) at ../my.c:13
13      int main(int argc, char **argv) {
(gdb) n
18              fp = fopen("~/my.txt", "w");
(gdb) n
20              setvbuf(fp, buffer, _IOFBF, sizeof(buffer));
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

My environment is:

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 myhost 1.7.25(0.270/5/3) 2013-08-31 20:37 x86_64 Cygwin
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.1
```

Comment: Did you check the return value of `fopen`?

Comment: As @Oli suggests, your `fopen` call is almost certainly failing (hint: `~` is a shell thing, not a system thing) - time to start learning about error checking...

Comment: @Both - Yes, that was the problem.  That will be the last time I open a file without error checking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As informed by [Oli's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954122/segmentation-fault-calling-setvbuf#comment27991936_18954122) and [Paul R's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954122/segmentation-fault-calling-setvbuf#comment27992085_18954122), I added the appropriate error handling:

```
fp = fopen("~/my.txt", "w");
if (fp == NULL)
  {
    perror ("The following error occurred");
    printf( "Value of errno: %d\n", errno );
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
```

And the output was:

```
The following error occurred: No such file or directory
Value of errno: 2
```

After fixing the file path to a full path, the call to `setvbuf` was successful.